# Random variable question.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

Could someone please explain why in the following answer to the above question, do we write n>1/w? How do we know that this is the way to solve this question? And why is the word "hence" in the solution? What does w>1/n have to do with Xn(w) = 0 -> 0? And this is a silly question but could someone also tell me what does "(w)" refer to  in Xn(w)? I know that X is a random variable but what does it mean when we add a "(w)" after it? Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: its a way to organize the proof, that is, being $\omega \in(0,1]$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>\omega ^{-1}$ for all $n\geqslant N$, therefore $X_n(\omega )=0$ for all $n\geqslant N$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty }X_n(\omega )=0$. As the chosen $\omega $ was arbitrary we conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty }X_n= 0$. We don't know that this is **the** way to solve the exercise, it just **some** way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random variable is a real-valued measurable function on a probability space. A probability space is often denoted by $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$ as you wrote. An element of $\Omega$ is usually denoted by $\omega$.
Let $Z$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$. Then, $Z(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$. Usually, $\omega$ is omitted when we write $Z$.

Here $$X_n (\omega) = n I_{(0,1/n]}(\omega) = \begin{cases} n \ \omega  \in (0,1/n] \\ 0 \ \ \ \omega > 1/n\end{cases}.$$

Since for each $\omega \in \Omega$ there exists $N$ such that for every $n \ge N$ $\omega > 1/n$, in particular, $X_n (\omega) = 0$.

The confusion might occur due to the setting that $\Omega = (0,1]$, which is not necessarily a usual taking of a probability space and might be mistakenly regarded as a *state* space, but there is no problem for assuming that $\Omega = (0,1]$.